# I can not find mod_wsgi model in Apache modules environment - Django

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am new to Django and I tried to connect it with Apache through mod_wsgi but it seems new versions of Apache does not support such kind of module. Am I right? Or is there any different way I could deploy my Django project in production? I saw on the official page I could use nginx. Any opinions?

Comment: Try asking in Serverfault.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Incidentally, when you do post there, please include as much detail as you can (i.e. operating system, django version, apache version..etc)  mod_wsgi should work but you need to install it